# Integrating square of derivative of log function

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms

It is well known that 
$$
\int \frac{f'(x)dx}{f(x)}= \int d \log f(x)=\log f(x) + C
$$

In my work I came across the following case: 
$$
\int \frac{(f'(x))^2dx}{f(x)}
$$

I wonder if any interesting approach exists in this situation

Comment: Probably not. For example, if $f(x)=e^{x^2}$, then $(f')^2/f=4x^2e^{x^2}$, which has no elementary antiderivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating by parts gives,

$$ \int \frac{f'(x)f'(x)dx}{f(x)} = f'(x)\ln(f(x)) - \int f''(x)\ln(f(x))dx \,.$$

Comment: which makes things even more complicated, but thanks anyway.